# How to have slideshow along with Ui slider?

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

I got the slider bar from this example
http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/377_slider/slider_sourcefiles/slider.html
But i need the slide show of the images shown along with the progress in slide bar.How can i do that?